# A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, gdi+

I am running an MVC3 app on Mono/linux and everything is working fine with the exception of an image upload utility. Whenever an image upload is attempted i get the Invalid Parameter error from within the method below:

```
    System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus(status As Status) (unknown file): N 00339
    System.Drawing.Bitmap.SetResolution(xDpi As Single, yDpi As Single)
```

I've googled this error extensively and have found that the Invalid parameter error can often be misleading, and could fire if for example there was an error with the upload itself, or if the image was not fully read. This runs fine on IIS/Windows, but I've not been able to get it to work in Mono.

Apache2
Mono 2.10.8.1

Am i missing something simple or do i need to find a different way to handle image manipulation for mono?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing quite a bit of testing, I was able to determine the root of my error. I was attempting to use the **Image.HorizontalResolution** and **Image.VerticalResolution** properties for **Bitmap.Resolution** . While these properties were set on the initial upload (where the file is read into a stream from the tmp directory), when i posted back with the base64 encoded string of the image itself, it appears these values were lost somehow. Because of this the SetResolution method failed.

For whatever reason i do not have this issue on IIS/Windows, the properties exist in both circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. A Bitmap loaded from disk, reported bmp.HorizontalResolution==0 and bmp.VerticalResolution==0 when they were both==300. This behaviour does not occur on Windows.

A bit more digging, I found that the following test fails:

```
    [Test]
    public void GDI_SetResoltion()
    {
        var b1 = new Bitmap (100, 100);
        Assert.That (b1.HorizontalResolution, Is.Not.EqualTo (0));
        Assert.That (b1.VerticalResolution, Is.Not.EqualTo (0));
    }
```

I believe Windows will default resolution to 96 dpi.